How to make the text cursor/indicator go from right when an option is selected in react-select?
so i've been search for a solution for almost 3 hours, and i can't find a single one, so im writing here.
im using react-select library for an auto-complete, how to make the text indicator/cursor in the input text at the right (end of the input text value) upon selecting an option
so at the image below, the text indicator should be at the right-side not on the left-side when an option is selected
image from react-select docs
I tried overwriting the Input in Components props but didn't work, tried to look in the documentation but there's none addressing this issue.
